# Removing trace amounts of water from agricultural grade anhydrous ammonia

Tags: everyday-chemistry, purification

Agricultural grade anhydrous ammonia (liquefied gas) contains 2000 ppm $\ce{H2O}$. What would be the process to remove this water to obtain refrigeration grade (<100 ppm $\ce{H2O}$) anhydrous ammonia?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour]. Is it possible you are talking about ammonia chloride, as 100% pure ammonia would be a gas at room temperature.

Comment: Hi Martin:  No, I am talking about drying 20 ton truckloads of anhydrous ammonia. This would make agricultural grade anhydrous ammonia suitable for use in industrial refrigeration systems.  Thanks.

Comment: We haul it as a liquefied gas (under pressure).

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks for clearing this up. I added this information to your question just to make sure it does not get lost.

Answer (score 1):

Calcium oxide can get water down to 4ppm in anhydrous ammonia according to http://www.google.com/patents/US4075306.